# Alternative bash script to check if a process is running

Tags: bash

What would be the easiest and the most reliable way to check if a process is running in a script using bash?

Here´s what i have:

```
x=`ps aux | grep firefox | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2 }'`

if [ $x > 0 ];
then kill -9 $x
echo "Firefox terminated"
else echo "bla bla bla"
fi
```

Comment: If you have a semi-colon after your if statement, you don't need to break `then` to its own line.

Comment: Also, this is as good of a way as any. Another option might be `pgrep`, but it's not necessarily available on all platforms.

Comment: In general, "grep text and kill" is not a reliable way to kill processes.  Consider if you want to kill firefox, but not firefox_auto_update... Your simple grep will also kill firefox_auto_update.

Even if a solution can kill a process with a definite program path (pkill, for example, but I am not so sure...), you still have multiple instance problem: many 'firefox' are launched, which do you want to kill?  A specific one, or all of them? (All of them would be easy).

Comment: I am not sure if what application exactly you want to kill, but many application does write its PID somewhere.  For example, cron daemon writes its PID in /var/run/crond.pid.  Your first priority to kill an application is to look for the official place it keeps the PID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if x=$(pgrep firefox); then
    kill -9 $x
    # ...
fi
```

If you just want to kill the process:

```
pkill -9 firefox
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use `pgrep` to do this ?

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pgrep):

> pgrep looks through the currently running processes and lists the process IDs which matches the selection criteria to stdout.

Example:

```
$> pgrep firefox | xargs -r kill -9
```

In this example, the pid of the process is used by the `kill` command. The `-r` option of `xargs` allows to execute the `kill` command only if there is a pid.

Comment: Is pgrep supported in redhat?

Comment: I can't tell you for sure, but I guess it is, it's a very common tool.

Answer (score 1):

What about :

```
pkill &>/dev/null firefox && echo "ff terminated" || echo "no ff PIDs"
```

No need `-9` signal here ;)

Answer (score 0):

Pidof:

```
x=`pidof firefox`
if [[ $x > 0 ]];
then
kill -9 $x
echo "Firefox terminated"
else
echo "bla bla bla"
fi
```